# Как отправить сообщение по WSS?

Tags: javascript, websocket

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://artgrek.ru:8143", ); 
ws.send(JSON.stringify(LoginMessage));
```

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still
>   in CONNECTING state

UPD

Вопрос снят, порт 8143 не открыл на сервере.

UPD Вопрос открыт, я ошибся, ошибка на месте.

К тому же, даже если убрать ws.send, через секунд 5-10 появляется ошибка

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://artgrek.ru:8143/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Дождитесь соединения и уже потом отправляйте, ваш кэп. Событие onopen упоминается в любой документации

Comment: @andreymal если оставить только var ws = new WebSocket("wss://artgrek.ru:8143", ); то по таймауту вылетает ошибка как в дополнении вопроса

Comment: Пробуйте подключиться сначала локально, если прокатит - проблема в портах